# TokenEdit Usage - To automatically complete each data entered in the text box

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

I'm doing a Paint Sales Program in C # - DevExpress with EF. In the SQL Server database. When entering orders I need to enter more than one paint pattern in a TextBox (TextBoxEdit). Normally, I can call that record with autocomplete when I enter a record, but all I want is a few patterns that I have entered. Separating patterns with commas. I used TokenEdit in DevExpress for this, but it doesn't have a DataSource property, so it gives an error when transferring the data inside it to the BindingSource that I've linked to the grid.

How do I proceed? Could you please help I haven't found a valid solution for 1 week. There are people here who are more knowledgeable than me, so maybe you have a different solution to the problem.

I will be glad if you help me.

Thank you.

I will be glad if you help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use anther table in the database?  The paint pattern would be in the separate table.  Then you can link the current table to the new table using a Primary key.  The when a value changes in the current table you can get the paint pattern from the second table.

Comment: @jdweng 
I already do that.

Comment: Paint patterns are kept on separate table. When I enter data into my main table, I transfer and save the relevant data from a pattern table to the main table

Comment: Your datasource has to have the same number of columns as the view.  So you would need to create a new datasource that contains the same number of columns as the grid.  You can do the by creating a new Binding instead of using a datasource.  Then use binding to put data in the grid.

Comment: @jdweng 
When I use the ComboBox, the data appears in the gridControl. The problem was when I changed the comboBox with TokenEdit. Does not transfer the Texts of TokenEdit to the grid.

Comment: May be the grid is not getting repainted.  The data may be there but the view didn't update.  I often use DataGridView and to get the view to update I need to do following : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;  Otherwise the view doesn't change.

Comment: @jdweng
I understood thank you. Is there a way to provision TokenEdit with a Binding Source? Do you have any knowledge about this topic because I using Entity?

Comment: Read msdn article from 2016 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms